# How to change language in a Django+Selenium test?

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, internationalization

Why would Selenium not work with multiple languages?

I'm trying to write a Selenium test for a multi-language Django app. Everything works, until I try to change the user's language.

I have a `/set-language/` path, which calls:

```
@login_required
def set_language(request):
    lang = request.GET.get('l', 'en')
    request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = lang
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang)
    return response
```

I have Django's internationalization support to pull the language from this session variable. It works perfectly in the dev server. However, when I call it in a Selenium test with:

```
driver.get('/set-language/?l=ja')
```

Selenium throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 461, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/tests/test_lang.py", line 44, in test_language
    driver.get(reverse('set_language') + '?l=ja')
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 353, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//localhost/admin/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20localhost.
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
UnknownError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:513:5
checkReadyState@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:65:24
onNavigation@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:333:39
emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.jsm:160:20
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteEventsParent.jsm:44:25
```

and the browser is unable to bring up the page.

Does Selenium not support any languages besides English?

Answer (score 0):

To change the language, you can set the `locale_code` in `prefs`:

```py
prefs = {}
prefs["intl.accept_languages"] = "en_us"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Here's a full script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {}
prefs["intl.accept_languages"] = "en_us"
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

For a full list of locale codes to use with Selenium, see: https://seleniumbase.github.io/help_docs/locale_codes/

Comment: You misunderstand me. I need to change the language on the server side, through Selenium. The language in Selenium is already set to en_us and it crashes when it switches to Japanese.